# On Snow Leopard, the default unzip tool won't ask for password but just report it can't unzip?

Tags: snow-leopard, zip

Yesterday, I zipped up something using 7-zip on the PC, using a password for the zip file.  So if I copy the file to another PC and unzip, it asks for the password and restore the file.  However, if I copy the file to a Mac with Snow Leopard and double click on that file, it will simply say, can't unzip the file.  ([Archive Utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_Utility) was the app).

For me, since I know UNIX, I tried to open up Terminal and typed in

```
unzip foo.zip
```

and it actually asked for the password and unzipped for me, but I just wonder, what about if I don't use Terminal, or for people who are not familiar with the command line, how can it be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think the built-in decompression utility can unzip password protected files.  However, [The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html) is the way to go for all things compression related on OS X anyway.

Comment: the Archive.app DOES NOT support password protected files.

Comment: @KassymDorsel: You're referring to the default one that ships with the OS, not the unarchiver, correct?

Comment: That is correct. TheUnarchiver is the best free alternative to the built in Archive app.

Comment: Can you use it to view the contents of a compressed archive?

Comment: You can use a free QuickLook plugin : http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26511/betterzip-quick-look-generator Otherwise you will have to get a shareware app

Comment: hmmm... so it's not entirely "the way to go for all things compression related"; cool quicklook plugin though, thanks.

Comment: Any app from the App Store is good for it?  I usually feel cautious about installing 3rd party app (unless it is Firefox or Chrome), because you never know how much to trust each app or author.  The Unarchiver seems to be praised by people, although the webpage of it looks a little of a hobbyist's site and kind of a 90s look.